# Lowering minSdkVersion: Could my application run on lower SDK version?

Tags: android

I developed an application with compatibility to SDK level 10.
In order to make the application available for wider range of users, I'm considering lowering the API level to 8.

Is it as simple as changing the `minSdkVersion` value in manifest?
How can I make sure that I didn't use any API calls that exist only on API>=10?

Comment: The newer versions of Android Lint warn you when you use methods meant for higher API's then your TargetSDK. Lower your TargetSDK first to test it out and see if you get more Lint errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will run on previous platforms, Only if you did not use parts of API that are not available at previous platforms. One thing to do is to try to compile against the lower platform (You can install lower platforms in you SDK manager). The compile errors, if any, will point out the places in your code where you used non existing API. Also, watch out for *deprecated* warnings while compiling on recent platforms.

Comment: You should point out that compiling against a lower API version means lowering the targetSDKVersion, not the minimumSDKVersion. Anyway, if you use Eclipse and set the minimumSDKVersion Lint will produce warnings when you use method calls that are not available on all targets. In that case you'll have to check VERSION.SDK_INT or even better use the respective classes of the Compatibility Package.

Comment: @cypressious I trust Compiler more than Lint. And I'm not making any assumption about what kind of IDE OP uses.